# Creating a function to simplify WolframAlpha query

Tags: functions, wolfram-alpha-queries

When I can't remember an integral I usually just query wolfram and have it show steps.

This was my naive attempt at trying to make a simpler function.

```
 wolfram[query_] = 
 WolframAlpha[ToString[query], IncludePods -> "Input", 
  AppearanceElements -> {"Pods"}, PodStates -> {"Input__Show steps"}]
```

It doesn't work. I'm completely clueless :) More generally I'm asking: How would I create a permanent function to simplify something this... verbose ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For indefinite integrals where "Show Steps" is available, the pod state is `"IndefiniteIntegral__Step-by-step solution"`. The following works for cases where W|A can show the steps.

```
showSteps[query_] := WolframAlpha[
    "integrate " <> ToString[query], 
    {{"IndefiniteIntegral", 2}, "Content"}, 
    PodStates -> {"IndefiniteIntegral__Step-by-step solution"}
]
```

[image]

The `2` in the second argument refers to the hidden steps. Using `1` instead will give you the formatted result.

To get a computable result (formatting free) from W|A, you can use the following:

```
integrate[query_] := WolframAlpha[
    "integrate " <> ToString[query], 
    {{"IndefiniteIntegral", 1}, "ComputableData"}, 
    PodStates -> {"IndefiniteIntegral__Step-by-step solution"}
]

integrate["sin(x)^2"] // InputForm
(* Hold[Integrate[Sin[x]^2, x] == (x - Cos[x]*Sin[x])/2] *)
```